# Suppress/obfuscate URL in logcat

Tags: android, uri, logcat

I would like to hide/obscure a URL for a videoview in my application. CUrrently, the URL is displayed in the logcat when the videoactivity runs on the device. I would like to hide the URL as much as possible. Is there any way to suppress this output to the logcat?

Here is the offending activity:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        path = b.getString("path");
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

Comment: please check if you add to your `<application>` tag in your manifest `android:debuggable="false"` do these still appear in the logcat?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, there could be a solution:

If you take a look at the source of `VideoView`, you'll see that it calls [`MediaPlayer.setDataSource(..)`](http://www.google.com/codesearch#cZwlSNS7aEw/frameworks/base/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java&exact_package=android&q=mediaplayer&type=cs&l=704), which in turn calls `URI.getScheme()` and `URI.getPath()`.

Sooo, you might get around your problem by subclassing URI and overriding `toString()` which is used by Log. Make it return some descriptive info (media name?) but not the URL to media.

Comment: that's a good idea. Except how can I have the toString() return something aside from the uri and not have it effect the mediaplayer. I have been looking through the code and can't seem to find where its outputting to the log....

Comment: uptdate: looking at the log it seems like its StageFrightPlayer that is logging to logcat. It's a .cpp. any idea how to override THAT?